# Space items evenly on a stackpanel -Silverlight

Tags: .net, silverlight, xaml

I have a `<StackPanel>` control that I am populating with a `TextBox` controls.

I want to Vertically space evenly the `TextBox` objects. However with my code all three TextBoxes are still grouped at the top of the `<StackPanel>` even though I have set `VerticalAligment` to Stretch.

Also not sure if this helps, my LayoutRoot is a Grid 8 x 8 and the border alignes to fill most of the LayoutRoot

I cant manually assign a margin to each text box either as the `StackPanel` will be populated manually and the number of `TextBoxes` can vary.

```
    <Border  
        Grid.Row="1" 
        Grid.RowSpan="6"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="8"
        BorderBrush="Black"
        Background="White">

            <StackPanel x:Name="listItems" 
                Grid.Row="1" 
                Grid.RowSpan="6"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="8"
                Margin="10"

                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch">

                   <TextBox Text="line 1" />
                   <TextBox Text="line 2" />
                   <TextBox Text="line 3" />

            </StackPanel>

    </Border>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`UniformGrid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.uniformgrid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to achieve that evenly distributed vertical space with dynamic number of `TextBlock`s. For example :

**XAML :**

```
<UniformGrid x:Name="listItems" 
    Grid.Row="1" 
    Grid.RowSpan="6"
    Grid.Column="0"
    Grid.ColumnSpan="8"
    Margin="10"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
```

**Code-behind :**

```
//populate the UniformGrid dynamically from code :
int numberOfRow = 3;
listItems.Columns = 1;
listItems.Rows = numberOfRow;
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRow; i++)
{
    var txt = new TextBlock { Text = "test " + i };
    listItems.Children.Add(txt);
}
```

Comment: I cant seem to be able to find the Uniform Grid ? is it part of a third party sdk ?

Comment: Found it. I couldnt find one by MSFT but I have the ComponentOne tools for Silverlight. Your code worked perfectly without any changes

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/devdave/archive/2008/07/26/layout-fundamentals-part-2-layout-containers.aspx It does a really good job of explaining the Silverlight layout panels and their options. I would use a grid with vertical alignment of stretch and grid row definitions of no height set as this will evenly divide the available space between the grid rows for you.  Something like so:

```
<Border  
    Grid.Row="1" 
    Grid.RowSpan="6"
    Grid.Column="0"
    Grid.ColumnSpan="8"
    BorderBrush="Black"
    Background="White">

        <Grid x:Name="listItems" 
            Grid.Row="1" 
            Grid.RowSpan="6"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="8"
            Margin="10"

            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
               <RowDefinition />
               <RowDefinition />
               <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

               <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Text="line 1" />
               <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Text="line 2" />
               <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Text="line 3" />

        </Grid>

</Border>
```

Comment: Yes it looks like I will have to use a grid. thanks for the link I will read it tonight